# HTML5 player wont play video from subdomain on smartphone

Tags: javascript, android, html, video

What is the problem with video tag and HTML5, i can start videos but seek does not work from subdomain on smartphone, when i try in browser and PS all working fine

This is working fine, and seeking working here, but when i change src for video files to subdomain, video is start but seeking not working

```
<video id="videoPlayer"
        src="1.mp4"
        style="width:720px; height:440px;"
        controls="controls"
        type="video/mp4"
        onClick="this.play();">
</video>
```

EDIT: Its not working from my storage server, where is installed lighttpd... from subdomain where is apache seek working fine

Answer (score 0):

try the following code if it helps:

```
<video id="video player" 
  width="720"
  height="440" controls>
    <source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4" onClick=this.play()>
</video>
```

Hope this helps out

Comment: add certain modifications as per requirements.